# Check duplicates in CSV parsed file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, csv, parsing

I have a parsed CSV file in such format:

```
const data = [
    ["ID", "Full name", "pHone", "Email", "Age", "Experience", "Yearly Income", "Has children", "License states", "Expiration date", "License number", "Duplicated With"],
    [1, "Alex Cho", "+18900991919", "cho.cho@gmail.com", "12", "21", "200", "FALSE", "AL | New York | District of Columbia | Montana", "12-12-2030", "1xr567", null],
    [2, "Alex Cho", "1900991919", "12351235@yandex.ru", "0", "12", "true", "TRUE", "Alabama | American Samoa", "12/31/1998", "1xr567", null].
    [3, "Alex Cho", "8982394689", "alex.swarts@ukr.net", "-1", "8", "1200.11", "FALSE", "Northern Mariana Islands", "date", "kas317", null],
    [4, "Alex Cho", "18900991919", "cho.cho", "-99", "100", "1200.100", "YES", "Palau", "02-11-2021", "1nasd567213", null],
    [5, "Alex Cho", "+18900991919", "testEmail@gmail.com", "11", "11", "12..00.11", "NO", "Puerto Rico", "04-11-2021", "1xr567!(%^!@)", null],
    [6, "Alex Cho", "+18900991919", "@!%*!&@!@@gmail.com", "100", "10", "999999.11", " ", "West Virginia | North Carolina | North Dakota", "12/31/2022", "1xr*@#", null],
    [7, "Alex Cho", "+10950943225", "(*!&@^$%12481Asd@gMAIL.com)", "44", "10", "12.00.11", "TRUE", "Virgin Islands", "  2022-12-03", "1xr___", null],
    [8, "Alex Cho", "+10950943225", "(*!&@^$%12481Asd@gMAIL.com)", "44", "10", "12.00.11", "TRUE", "Virgin Islands", "  2022-12-03", "ABC123", null],
]
```

Now I need to check it for duplicates for email and phone if the phone or email will be the same in any items, I need to notice it and make a mark in my created last column "duplicated with". If you can see on the picture, there is an additional column and there must be an ID of duplicates.

But also, I don't know how to implement this.
[image]

Comment: Would be helpful if you simply showed the desired outcome of the array.

Comment: @codemonkey well, I need something like this: 
First element have ID 5, the second have ID 10
["+18900991919", "testEmail@gmail.com", 10],
["+18900991919", "@!%*!&@!@@gmail.com, 5],

Comment: What's the ID value? array index + 1?

Comment: @codemonkey yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I am understanding your requirements correctly. You need somethig like this it seems:

```js
const data = [
    ["ID", "Full name", "pHone", "Email", "Age", "Experience", "Yearly Income", "Has children", "License states", "Expiration date", "License number", "Duplicated With"],
    ["1", "Alex Cho", "+18900991919", "cho.cho@gmail.com", "12", "21", "200", "FALSE", "AL | New York | District of Columbia | Montana", "12-12-2030", "1xr567"],
    ["2", "Alex Cho", "1900991919", "12351235@yandex.ru", "0", "12", "true", "TRUE", "Alabama | American Samoa", "12/31/1998", "1xr567"],
    ["3", "Alex Cho", "8982394689", "alex.swarts@ukr.net", "-1", "8", "1200.11", "FALSE", "Northern Mariana Islands", "date", "kas317"],
    ["4", "Alex Cho", "18933991919", "cho.cho", "-99", "100", "1200.100", "YES", "Palau", "02-11-2021", "1nasd567213"],
    ["5", "Alex Cho", "+18900991222", "testEmail@gmail.com", "11", "11", "12..00.11", "NO", "Puerto Rico", "04-11-2021", "1xr567!(%^!@)"],
    ["6", "Alex Cho", "+18933991919", "@!%*!&@!@@gmail.com", "100", "10", "999999.11", " ", "West Virginia | North Carolina | North Dakota", "12/31/2022", "1xr*@#"],
]

const new_data = data.map((item, index) => {
    const clean_phone = item[2].replace(/^(\+1|^1)/,""); //Clean up the phone number
    const dup_ids = [];
    data.forEach((element, ind) => {
        if((index !== ind) && (element[2].includes(clean_phone) || item[3] === element[2]))
            dup_ids.push(element[0])
    })

    index && item.push(dup_ids);
    return item;
});
console.log(new_data)
```

This will give you the same array, but append an array of all duplicate "IDs" found by phone or email in the same array.

Comment: hello, I have updated my array, can you make the same with the new array, also, you can don't accept the first element with headers

Comment: @AlexeyPetrenko Updated.

Answer (score 0):

you have at least two choices:

1. sort the array by phone and email and then loop over the array comparing each entry with the next one. If they are the same flag the current record as duplicate to the previous one.
2. using a map (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), loop over the array (no need to sort it first) and check if the phone+email entry exists in the map. If it does, the current entry is duplicate and if not add to the map with a key= phone + email and value of the number of the record.

Comment: I have updated an array, but I don't understand, how to check it